# Questions about flow work/flow energy?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am having a few questions about 'flow work' and the First law of thermodynamics when applying to a closed non-stationary system.

I know for a non-stationary close system, say an element(Lagrangian) of fluid, the First law can be written as

$Q=U+W+KE+PE$

i)If the kinetic energy ($KE$) and the potential energy ($PE$) of this element of fluid are negligible
then

$Q=U+W$

If we consider the element to undergo an adiabatic process then

$U=-W$

Usually, the work W here is taken to be the $PdV$ work (boundary work). But what if the element is incompressible? Then can we substitute the $Vdp$ work here? i.e.

$U = -VdP$

ii) I have read multiple posts that state that Vdp is the flow work. But for a control volume through which mass flow is taking place, we usually call $PV$ the flow-work. What is the difference between the $PV$ flow work and the $VdP$ flow work and why do they have the same name?

Ref: [How to apply first law of thermodynamics closed non-stationary incompressible element of fluid passing a nozzle?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/718159/how-to-apply-first-law-of-thermodynamics-closed-non-stationary-incompressible-el)

Comment: vdP is the shaft work per unit mass passing through the control volume,  d(Pv) is the net amount of work required for force fluid into and out of the control volume per unit mass; the latter is usually lumped together with the internal energy change per unit mass. to give the enthalpy change per unit mass.  You need to review the derivation of the open system version of the 1st law of thermodynamics  to understand the distinction between total work and shaft work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Usually, the work W here is taken to be the $PdV$ work (boundary
> work). But what if the element is incompressible? Then can we
> substitute the $Vdp$ work here? i.e.
>
> $U = -VdP$

No.

$VdP$ is differential flow work. Flow work is associated with pushing fluid across the boundaries into and out of an open system. It does not apply to a closed system where, by definition, mass does not cross the boundary. For an adiabatic closed system consisting of an incompressible fluid, boundary work is zero and therefore the change in internal energy is zero.

> What is the difference between the $PV$ flow work and the $VdP$ flow
> work and why do they have the same name?

$Pv$ work refers to the flow work at the inlet ***or*** outlet  of the open system control volume. The *net* $Pv$ work in moving the fluid both into ***and***  out of the control volume is $\Delta (Pv)$ or $P_{e}v_{e}-P_{i}v_{i}$ where $i$ and $e$ are the inlet and exit pressure and specific volume.

In general, the net reversible flow work, in the absence of changes in kinetic and potential energy, is given by

$$w_{rev}=-\int_i^e vdP$$

For an incompressible fluid ($v$ = constant)

$$w_{rev}=-v(P_{e}-P_i)$$

For reversible adiabatic flow the net flow work equals the net output work of the system, typically shaft work.

Regarding your follow up question, yes you can get the same result tracking an element of compressible fluid and treating it as a closed system. But in that case $du=-Pdv$, where $Pdv$ is the boundary work on the element. The reversible adiabatic turbine work $dw_{T}$ is based on the change in enthalpy $dh$ of the element as it passes through the control volume. In general $dh=Tds +vdP$.  For an adiabatic reversible turbine, $ds=0$ and therefore $dw_{T}=dh=vdP$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to understand the energy equation by tracking an element of fluid (closed system) in a flow, say through a turbine. When every flow is involved the Open system/control volume approach is applied. But the same result should be obtained by following the energy interaction with a 'closed' element of fluid too. How do i write the energy equation for an incompressible element of fluid passing through a turbine? I know the element loses (internal) energy and also the (static)pressure drops  (ignoring KE and PE changes)?

Comment: I know that the change in internal energy will be equal to the work done dU=W.

Comment: @GRANZER You can get the same result by tracking an element of fluid and treating it as a closed system. But $W$  is boundary work on the element, not turbine work produced by the element. I will update my answer to elaborate.

Comment: Thank you, that will be very helpful!

Comment: @GRANZER See my update. Hope it helps.

Comment: What about for incompressible element of fluid? For example, let's consider pressurizing a certain volume of an incompressible fluid, say in a tank by placing weights. Now even though pressure has increased the internal energy has not increased since there is no boundary work done here. If we consider any arbitrary constant volume element of fluid in the tank AND if we open a hole in the tank the KE of the element will increase and the pressure will decrease. Where did the energy come to increase the kinetic energy? I know by pressure difference but don't know how to represent it in FLT.

Comment: @GRANZER If the element is incompressible it can still due turbine work due to pressure forces on the turbine blades. Regarding the rest of your comments they go well beyond your original question, where we assumed changes in KE and PE are negligible. In any case, the KE comes from the gravitational PE. I don't know what FLT means.  Have I answered your original question satisfactorily?

Comment: Because what you are now asking is a fluid mechanics question, not thermodynamics, involving Bernoulli’s equation for incompressible fluid flow

Comment: Sorry, FLT is the First law of thermodynamics. I had to write the short form due to the character limit for a single comment. As you said the incompressible element could do turbine work due to pressure. I am still not clear on how to write the equation for this. Can you please help me with that.? As you have written change in the internal energy of the element is not equal to VdP..

Comment: @GRANZER Are you familiar with Bernoulli's equation?

Comment: Yes I am familiar with the Bernoullis equation but I only know how to derive it from the steady flow energy equation which is applicable for an open system. How to derive it from the first law of thermodynamics applied to a closed nonstationary element?

Comment: @GRANZER Before we go off in this new direction, have I or have I not satisfactorily answered the original question as presented?

Comment: Not yet but almost. As I had mentioned I am trying to understand the FLT applied to an incompressible element of fluid. As you mentioned it can do 'turbine work' due to pressure. That is what I was looking for. The 'how' this pressure work is to be incorporated into the FLT would be the solution. Because the pressure and volume get mentioned in the FLT for a closed system only due to PdV boundary work. FLT for the open system has it by default due to the flow work. How is the pressure work that you mentioned is to be incorporated for a non-stationary incompressible closed system?