# How to apply first law of thermodynamics closed non-stationary incompressible element of fluid passing a nozzle?

Tags: thermodynamics

The First Law of Thermodynamics (FLT) applied to a closed non-stationary incompressible element of fluid is given as

$Q-W = \Delta(KE)+\Delta(PE)+\Delta U$ .......(Eq1)

where:

- $\Delta U$ is change in internal energy;
- $\Delta (KE)$ is the change in Kinetic energy;
- $\Delta (PE)$ is the change in Potential energy;
- $Q$ is the amount of heat supplied to the system;
- $W$ is the amount of work done by the system to the environment.

(Let's assume $\Delta (PE)$ is zero)

If this element of fluid is going through a (converging)nozzle, from Bernoulli's law I can say that the pressure energy is transferred to kinetic energy, and at the end of the nozzle, the fluid's flow rate/velocity has increased. But how to deduce it from FLT applied to a closed non-stationary system (i.e $Eq1$) without using the Steady-flow-energy-equation(SFEE)/FLT-applied-to-open system?

The question is: I know how to analyze the flow through the nozzle as an Open system. How to do the same by applying FLW to a closed incompressible element of fluid passing the nozzle? How is the KE changing there are no pressure terms in Eq1 (and the is no PdV boundary work)?

PS: I am also trying to deduce how to apply the FLT to an incompressible element passing a turbine blade passage causing the turbine to rotate. Any help would be much appreciated.

Ref: [Questions about flow work/flow energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/717839/questions-about-flow-work-flow-energy/717895?noredirect=1#comment1605979_717895)

Comment: It is not quite clear what is given in the problem (like speed of the flow, pressure) and what are the attempts at reasoning.

Comment: @RogerVadim Let's say the velocity, static-pressure, and temperature before the nozzle are V1, P1, and T1 and the velocity, pressure, and temperature before the nozzle is V2, P2, and T2.  V1<V2 and P1>P2. I am guessing there is no change in temperature so  T1=T2 (from water flow in converging). The question is I know how to analyze the flow through the nozzle as an Open system. How to do the same by applying FLW to a closed incompressible element of fluid passing the nozzle?

Comment: Are you saying that you don't understand the derivation of the open system version of the 1st law of thermodynamics, starting from the closed system version?

Comment: @ChetMiller No I was wondering how to apply the FLT to a element that was going along with the flow as usually Opensystem analysis is used for flows except in when studying Reynolds transport theorem but wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I think the problem comes from the use of the expression $-PdV$ that is no longer valid here.

If the pressure at the surface of a closed system is not uniform, the work is not written $-PdV$. It is necessary to integrate on the surface of the closed system. One could write the integral and find that the result is non-zero when the pressure is not uniform. But it may be sufficient to consider the limiting case of a slice of incompressible fluid which advances with a velocity $v$ with different pressures $P_1$ on the left and $P_2$ on the right. The work during $dt$ is $(P_1-P_2)Svdt$ : clearly non zero. So the work term is not zero in your situation.

Hope my poor english is OK !

Edit : mathematical complement

We can write all this mathematically. The work of the pressure forces during $dt$ is an integral over the surface of the system : $\delta W=\iint{-P\vec{dS}\vec{v}dt}$

By Green's theorem, we replace it by a volume integral $\delta W/dt=-\iiint{\vec{\nabla}(P\vec{v})d\tau}$ with $\vec{\nabla}(P\vec{v})=P\vec{\nabla}(\vec{v})+\vec{\nabla}(P)\vec{v}$

For an incompressible flow, $\vec{\nabla}(\vec{v})=0$ it remains $\delta W/dt=-\iiint{\vec{\nabla}(P)d\tau\vec{v}}$.

Finally, for an elementary volume, we find : $\delta W/dt=(-\vec{\nabla}(P)d\tau)\vec{v}$

This is simply the power of the pressure force $\vec{dF}=-\vec{\nabla}(P)d\tau$ on the volume element.

Comment: So it is the work due to external pressure difference but without a easy way to write a equation for the work performed by it on the element?

Comment: I added a mathematical complement to clarify my answer.