# Why work is calculated by $Vdp$ when volume is constant in thermodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, work, gas, volume

[image]

Why work is equal to $-VdP$ when volume is constant? Doesn't that imply that work is equal to 0? Isn't work a result of volume change?

Comment: The volume is the volume and is a (non-zero) constant. The pressure changes, so $dP$ is a non-zero number. The product $VdP$ is non-zero.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Questions about flow work/flow energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/717839/)

Answer (score 1):

The original statement is incorrect.  At constant volume, $$dU=dH-VdP$$